# Trying to identify this font

Tags: font-identification

I just stumbled across this really neat font. Can anyone identify it? I'm referring to the text that says "360° OF SUCCESS"

[image]

Comment: that 6 appears to be a clumsily rotated 9.

Answer (score 4):

The best match, though not perfect, from [whatthefont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) seems to be:

[image]

There is very little to go on.
(personally, in this sort of typeface, I like the Chalet family: http://www.houseind.com/fonts/chalet/viewfonts

Comment: Pretty good. Thanks. Do you have a link for that "Eurotype Equalis"?

Comment: Its actually "Eurotypo" and...seriously?

Comment: @horatio Seriously what?

Comment: I think what @horatio is saying, is that a very simple web-search would reveal the foundry, and that footwork you can manage yourself.